# Google Sheets - Automatically create a new page and link to that page in a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I already have a piece of code that automatically creates a new page based on if a row of data is inputed, however I want to be able to get a link to that new page and automatically put that link in a cell on the original page (hopefully that makes sense) I don't have any coding knowledge however managed to get this piece of code working for the sheet through some googling. Hoping you will be able to help me; I've put the code I'm using for the automatic page creation below to show what I am working with.

```
function onEdit(e){
if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != "GAMES" || e.range.columnStart != 4) return;
const template = sh.getSheetByName("TEMPLATE");
let data = e.range.offset(0,-3,1,4).getValues();
let lName = data[0][0];

let newSheet = template.copyTo(sh).setName(lName);
}
```

Again not a coder but that current code is working really well just need it to do this extra bit if that is even possible. If not I will have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible. What you are looking for is to just set a simple formula. And utilize the hyperlink `#gid`

[setFormula Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)

[Hyperlink #gid](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?sjid=16625457033389961970-NC)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != "GAMES" || e.range.columnStart != 4) return;

  const sh = e.source;

  const template = sh.getSheetByName("TEMPLATE");

  let data = e.range.offset(0, -3, 1, 4).getValues();

  let lName = data[0][0];

  let newSheet = template.copyTo(sh).setName(lName);

  // Create a link to the new sheet in the column to the right of edited cell
  e.range.offset(0,1).setFormula('=HYPERLINK("#gid=' + newSheet.getSheetId() + '","Link to ' + lName + '")');
}
```

I didn't see where you declared `sh` so I added that in there. This will create a link to the new sheet in column E for example. Which it looks like you are already aware of how offset works so change as desired.

Comment: Great, so I would have to have the script I originally had + this running or it does both, sorry if its obvious just trying to understand.

Comment: No worries, this just added the final two lines to your existing script. It does it all in one go, considering you already had the moving parts in storage, I just set the formula in an adjacent cell to link to that sheet you created.

Comment: Perfect, just check and it does it exactly. Thanks!